# how to display output in textview using android?

Tags: java, android, cordova

i am newbie in  android and i m not getting how to produce this output:
Discipline name:1
{  complete for loop code execute from 0 to 9
}

then it will come outside and will update textview text:ie 
Discipline name:2 
and will enter inside For Loop
{
complete for loop code execute from 0 to 9
}

here is the java code:

```
public class SummaryDetailActivity extends Activity
{  TableLayout summaryDetailDisciplineTableLayout;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.summarydetail_view);
                 mInflater = getLayoutInflater();
summaryDetailDisciplineTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.summaryDetail_disciplinetable);
```

//PLEASE SEE THESE LINE OF CODE:

```
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
  TextView disciplineTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summaryDetail_disciplinetext);
  disciplineTextView.setText("discipline name: "+i);
 for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
{TableRow disciplineRow = (TableRow) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.summarydetailrow_view,null);
TextView disciplineDeviceLabel = (TextView) disciplineRow.findViewById(R.id.summaryDetail_info1);
TextView disciplineQuantityLabel = (TextView)disciplineRow.findViewById(R.id.summaryDetail_hypen);
 TextView disciplineLocationLabel = (TextView) disciplineRow.findViewById(R.id.summaryDetail_info2);
  disciplineDeviceLabel.setText("device no." + j);
disciplineQuantityLabel.setText("quantity No." + j);
  disciplineLocationLabel.setText("Location No." + j);
disciplineRow.setId(j);
  summaryDetailDisciplineTableLayout.addView(disciplineRow);
}

}
}
}
```

this code is producing this output:
[image: Snapshots of code]

Comment: are you adding disciplineRow.addView(disciplineDeviceLabel); ... etc ? before summaryDetailDisciplineTableLayout.addView(disciplineRow);

Comment: whats wrong in this post who is giving down votes i am newbie and i can ask this type of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why your code is not working the way you want. Is because this

```
TextView disciplineTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summaryDetail_disciplinetext);
```

is initiate as static view that can't be clone in your loop. That's why the value
of the discipline name is 1 not 0. The loop only update the value not clone the view.

You should do this

```
TextView disciplineTextView = new Textview(this);
disciplineTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
disciplineTextView.setText("discipline name: "+i);
summaryDetailDisciplineTableLayout.addView(disciplineTextView);

for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
-your code-
}
```

You should change the xml structure for better UI.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks your code works perfectly thanks u understand my question and respond me exaclty perfect code,thanks once again if u agree please upvote my question as well

Comment: can u please help me like the above code i also want to display DEVICE   QUANTITY  LOCATION   three textviews in horizontal orientation  after each dynamic textview i.e discipline name :0  then these three textviews appear  similarly discipline name:11 and three textviews right now i have done code but its displaying me in vertical direction even i have added orientation dynamically while my linear layout is already defined in xml code

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would've done it.
Inside my XML code, I would create a LinearLayout and within that, a TableLayout.

After fetching the id of my TableLayout, I would dynamically create TableRows and TextViews. You can set their layouts using TableRow.LayoutParams or LayoutParams. You can simply set the text after that and just add them onto the TableRow that you add to TableLayout.

Hope this suggestion helps !

Comment: please see output snapshot and suggest me what to do changes in code to produce my desired result

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `onCreate()` you should use inflater first and then set the view that you have just inflated.
Try this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.summarydetail_view, null);
setContentView(view);
```

Comment: please see output snapshot and suggest me what to do changes in code to produce my desired result